# OpenCV distinctive count from objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, color-detection

Hey I never used OpenCV before. Actually I want to realize a project where I need to count objects in real time from a camera, which can be differenced by theire colors such as red, blue or yellow. For example, I would drop continuously a lot of balls from above the filmed area. At the end I want the total number of red, blue and yellow balls.

Since I dont have any experience in using OpenCV I wanted to know, if such a object detection is possible in real time or close to it.

Comment: typically isn't trivial and depends a lot on the kind of objects you want to detect and probably track or re-recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is. But note that you may be limited by your hardware. You should search for sample code that perform **object tracking by color** in opencv to benchmark your machine. That is, if your problem is performance.

Comment: im thinking of using a raspberry pi :) but have not buyed one yet.